# jQuery: If this HREF contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I get this to work??

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this[href$="?"]).length()) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});
```

Ps.: This is just at simplifyed example, to make it easier for you to get an overview.

Comment: $("a").each(function() {
    console.debug($(this[href$="?"]);if ($(this[href$="?"]).length()) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You could just outright select the elements of interest.

```
$('a[href*="?"]').each(function() {
    alert('Contains question mark');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/TzUN3/

Note that you were using the [`attribute-ends-with` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), the above code uses the [`attribute-contains` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), which is what it sounds like you're actually aiming for.

Comment: @Matt - Note that quotes around the string to match are required in the current version of jQuery.

Comment: @Ender according to the API docs, you are right. In practice the quotes are not always necessary, though as you said, they are necessary here.

Comment: @Ender basically the regexp that jQuery uses to parse attribute selectors allows for either quotes _or_ no quotes, but I think the no-quotes is problematic here because `?` can have special meaning in a regexp. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/GYDQc/

Comment: Very cool.  I guess they're just playing it safe by having the docs say that quotes are required.  Amazing what you can learn by reading source code :)

Comment: This answer is pure gold, especially the j query article.

Answer (score 23):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if (this.href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});
```

Comment: It'd be even simpler with just `this.href` instead of the needless resort to jQuery. It's also not really correct, as the original question seemed to want to find a "?" at the *end* of the "href" value (which would be an understandable thing to do).

Comment: @Pointy I don't think the OP realized he's using the attribute-ends-with selector.

Comment: @Matt Ball well I understand why you might say that, but looking for a "?" at the end of an "href" might be a useful thing to do.  You may be correct, of course; it's also useful to look for a "?" *anywhere* in an "href".  The question is not terribly clear.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me this :)

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
$("a").each(function () {
    var href=$(this).prop('href');
    if (href.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because it's syntactically nonsensical. You simply can't do that in JavaScript like that.

You can, however, use jQuery:

```
  if ($(this).is('[href$=?]'))
```

You can also just look at the "href" value:

```
  if (/\?$/.test(this.href))
```

Comment: None of the above gives me an alert, eventhough there is a link with a questionmark in it...

Answer (score 2):

Along with the points made by others, the `$=` selector is the "[ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)" selector.  You will want the `*=` ([contains](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)) selector, like so:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[href*="?"')) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});
```

[Here's a live demo ->](http://jsfiddle.net/MC6aG/)

As noted by Matt Ball, unless you will need to also manipulate links without a question mark (which may be the case, since you say your example is simplified), it would be less code and much faster to simply select only the links you want to begin with:

```
$('a[href*="?"]').each(function() {
    alert("Contains questionmark");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($('[href$="?"]', this).length()) {
        alert("Contains questionmark");
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not work, because it's telling jQuery to look for an `<a>` tag that's a *descendant* of the `<a>` in the ".each()" context.