# Search divs for alt value the same as typed in searchbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contains, alt

I have a lot of divs with all alt names, if you type something in the searchbox i only wand the divs with the alt value that corresponds with the searchbox typed value to be vissible.

I can't place the searchbox typed value of ***`$('#kwd_search').val()`*** into the **''`[alt*= value ]`**.
Annyone have suggestions how it can be fixed?

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/807/md2zmdjs/).Source from: [(Searching HTML Table [closed])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325066/searching-html-table) , [(jQuery: If this HREF contains)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374682/jquery-if-this-href-contains)

Comment: Just google how to get the alt atribute from a html element. Its not that hard. document.getElementById('test').alt and compare it with the value of the input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$(".child[alt*=(searchboxValue)]").show();
```

To

```
$(".child[alt*="+searchboxValue+"]").show();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/md2zmdjs/2/

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond!, simple but could not find it on search engines anywhere. Also did not understand :contains()...

Comment: thats also works with contains :) $(".child:contains("+searchboxValue+")").show();

Comment: i would also recommend to add this instead of $(this).val(): var searchboxValue = $(this).val().replace(/ /g, '');

its ensure that all whitespaces will be remove and the user can also find "pudding" if he is typing "pudding " https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/md2zmdjs/5/

Comment: Now i know that to, great thank you! Oh (/ /g, ") stands for a whitespaces? That shure is clever.

Comment: No problem. Yes (/ /g, '') is a regular expression (regExp) which really remove ALL whitespaces. str.replace(' ', '') removes only one.

Comment: @kaito Better use `trim()` since user can typed space in the middle of the word.

Comment: str.trim() is also nice, yes. The use-case must be define what he need.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting searchboxValue as string not as value, try this:

```
$(".child[alt*=" + searchboxValue + "]").show();
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/md2zmdjs/3/)

Comment: Almost had it. Thanks for the quick respond! Looks simple, could have sworn i tried everything... I tried (' " ' + searchboxValue + ' " ') But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one. this works.

```
$(".child[alt*=" + $(this).val() + "]").show()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szxdtw5n/

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i did not know it was that simple. I expected you could not write script between (" "). Your sollution doesnt need a (var) which is nice, for now i keep the var(to be safe and for testing).